# I'm getting an error when installing Cordova

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

When I want to install Cordova with npm I get the following error:

```
Error: No compatible version found: ripple-emulator@'>=0.9.15'
```

Node,Nodejs, and npm are all installed. I couldn't find anything that could help.
 My command was:

```
npm install cordova
```

OR

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

Comment: Your Node.js version is probably too old. `ripple-emulator` requires at least `0.8.0`, check your version using `node -v`.

Comment: How did you install it? What does `which node` return?

Comment: Then you need to install a newer version from http://nodejs.org/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Node.js version is probably too old. `ripple-emulator` requires at least 0.8.0, check your version using `node -v`.

If that is the case, you either have to get a newer package from your distribution or download and install a newer version from [nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org/).

Answer (score 1):

That's what worked for me (though I installed with apt-get, I had node 0.6 whereas the more recent version was 0.10.31) :
Add node to your sources :

```
sudo apt-add-rep ository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
```

then update sources

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then install (or update) nodejs

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

source : http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/nodejs (in french)