# Cordova cannot install

Tags: cordova, npm

I posted a question (which people closed for no valid reason - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26149969/update-cordova-platform-3-5-1-not-working)

They refer to a solution which does not work since I get this error:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: cordova
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
```

any knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using native code using a webview using these websites:

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/

Updating Cordova never wored.

Answer (score 1):

First try to set npm registry using:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: I get: `npm ERR! error installing cordova@2.8.1` and

Comment: Run sudo npm install -g cordova

Comment: Still the same but i get more: `npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: ripple-emulator@'>=0.9.15'` `npm ERR! No valid targets found.`

Comment: seeb this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549807/im-getting-an-error-when-installing-cordova it suugest to update npm

Answer (score 0):

Try to update npm:

```
$ sudo npm install npm -g
```

and then update cordova

```
$ sudo npm install -g cordova
```